# Event handler in python serial port data received

Tags: python, events, serial-port

Im trying to write a code were a event is called each time a data is received in the serial port.
I'm using pyserial but I cannot find a code that works.

the ones that I've found are like

```
for True:
    inputb = ord(ser.read(1))
    'Rest of the code'
```

But I'm searching a way of adding a event when a byte has been read with a function like DataReady() or similar function that can trigger the event only when a valid data has arrived

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you’re okay doing away with some portability, you can use [`select.select`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.select) on it. (`select.select` itself is pretty portable, but using it with a serial port probably will only work on a POSIX system.)

Comment: What do you mean by "event is called"? Do you just want it to call a separate function when data is received? Or are you using a framework with event management like GTK or Twisted Python?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm Trying to make a analogy to visual studio. In visual studio you can import a serial port and add a event listener so when a valid byte has enter, it will go to that 'interruption' that handles the incoming data. The problem that I'm having with python is that the code will always be in the for loop and I cant work with other functions.

Comment: Take a look at this, I think it will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70625801/threading-reading-a-serial-port-in-python-with-a-gui

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Threading reading a serial port in Python (with a GUI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70625801/threading-reading-a-serial-port-in-python-with-a-gui)