# Threading reading a serial port in Python (with a GUI)

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, serial-port

I want to trigger an event whenever there is data to be read from a serial port while running a GUI. The `pySerial` module apparently has experimental functionality for that, but it isn't particularly well documented (I couldn't find any useful examples [in the API](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#module-serial.threaded)).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169219/constantly-reading-from-a-serial-port-with-a-background-thread) appears to deal with the same or at least very similar task, but doesn't provide instructions to replicate it or working code examples.

I came up with this code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import serial
import threading

# Create GUI window
window = tk.Tk()

# Initialize the port
myPort = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')

# Function to call whenever there is data to be read
def readFunc(port):
    port.readline()
    print('Line read')

# Configure threading
t1 = threading.Thread(target = readFunc, args=[myPort])
t1.start()

# Main loop of the window
window.mainloop()
```

Running it does indeed trigger the event, but only once. Why is that? Is there a "recommended" way to do this as by using the functionality of `pySerial` itself?

Alternatively, I would also run the function to read and process data on an event like you can with GUI elements. If that is the better solution, how would that be done?

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600753/event-handler-in-python-serial-port-data-received) (unanswered), probably makes this question a duplicate

Edit: Here is a minimal example derived from the answer below that changes the text of a label whenever data is read to the incoming data:

```py
import tkinter as tk

from serial import Serial
from serial.threaded import ReaderThread, Protocol

app = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(text="A Label")
label.pack()

class SerialReaderProtocolRaw(Protocol):
    port = None

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        """Called when reader thread is started"""
        print("Connected, ready to receive data...")

    def data_received(self, data):
        """Called with snippets received from the serial port"""
        updateLabelData(data)

def updateLabelData(data):
    data = data.decode("utf-8")
    label['text']=data
    app.update_idletasks()

# Initiate serial port
serial_port = Serial("/dev/ttyACM0")

# Initiate ReaderThread
reader = ReaderThread(serial_port, SerialReaderProtocolRaw)
# Start reader
reader.start()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try using while loop inside `readFunc()` to keep reading data from serial port.

Comment: I specifically don't want to poll the port, only call the function when there is data available to be read.

Comment: I'm searching through the `serial` source code, and I can't find this experimental functionality. Do you know where specifically in the module the code for it is? Or at least what it's called?

Comment: reading about the pySerial. It does not appear to be providing the feature that you are looking for.

_"I specifically don't want to poll the port, only call the function when there is data available to be read."_

How would you know if there is a data available to read? Are you expecting the serial port to notify your software?

Comment: In a way, yes I am expecting that. Or at least I don't want my own program to handle that like is done with the events triggered by GUI elements in tkinter. They can do it and this can be done in other software like Matlab so I expect it to be possible in python too.

Comment: Could not find anything that can avoid the loop.
However, you can explore : https://github.com/changyuheng/aioserial
or 
use [`select.select`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.select)  in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600753/event-handler-in-python-serial-port-data-received

Comment: `aioserial` doesn't seem to have any functionality like that either.

Comment: While `aioserial` can read data from a port when it is available, it can't do so alongside a main program (or at least I can't see how it would do that).

Comment: Example for [ReaderThread](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.threaded.ReaderThread) may help.

Comment: "it can't do so alongside a main program (or at least I can't see how it would do that)."
well this is the easy bit.. there are a couple of solutions..
you can use `root.after(delay, callback, args)` to spawn a new thread
or you can spwan a new thread yourself or 
use (my person favourite)  (ThreadPoolExecutor)https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor
or use ReaderThread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main concern is to be thread safe, when You are updating GUI from another running Thread.
To achieve this, we can use .after() method, which executes callback for any given tk widget.

Another part of Your request is to use Threaded serial reader.
This can be achieved by using [ReaderThread](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.threaded.ReaderThread) accompanied with Protocol.

You can pick two protocols:

- [raw data reader protocol](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.threaded.Protocol), which reads data as they come
- [line reader protocol](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.threaded.LineReader), which enables us to read lines of data

Here is working code example, with two protocols mentioned above, so You can pick which one suits You. Just remember, that all data coming from serial port are just raw bytes.

```
import tkinter as tk

from serial import Serial
from serial.threaded import ReaderThread, Protocol, LineReader


class SerialReaderProtocolRaw(Protocol):
    tk_listener = None

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        """Called when reader thread is started"""
        if self.tk_listener is None:
            raise Exception("tk_listener must be set before connecting to the socket!")
        print("Connected, ready to receive data...")

    def data_received(self, data):
        """Called with snippets received from the serial port"""
        self.tk_listener.after(0, self.tk_listener.on_data, data.decode())


class SerialReaderProtocolLine(LineReader):
    tk_listener = None
    TERMINATOR = b'\n\r'

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        """Called when reader thread is started"""
        if self.tk_listener is None:
            raise Exception("tk_listener must be set before connecting to the socket!")
        super().connection_made(transport)
        print("Connected, ready to receive data...")

    def handle_line(self, line):
        """New line waiting to be processed"""
        # Execute our callback in tk
        self.tk_listener.after(0, self.tk_listener.on_data, line)


class MainFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self)
        self.listbox.pack()
        self.pack()

    def on_data(self, data):
        print("Called from tk Thread:", data)
        self.listbox.insert(tk.END, data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = tk.Tk()

    main_frame = MainFrame()
    # Set listener to our reader
    SerialReaderProtocolLine.tk_listener = main_frame
    # Initiate serial port
    serial_port = Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0")
    # Initiate ReaderThread
    reader = ReaderThread(serial_port, SerialReaderProtocolLine)
    # Start reader
    reader.start()

    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive example, but I'm not sure I understand everything that is going on. What is the purpose of the `MainFrame`? what is the purpose of the `tk_listener`? I have put a minimum working example derived from this into the edited question.

Comment: tk_listener is necessary when You want to notify and update Your tk widget. Otherwise, You can't communicate with tk main thread. MainFrame is bascially Your container / widget holding some element that You want to update from other Thread (ReaderThread in our case). Of course, if You don't need to execute callback which will update / change some widget , You don't need to implement tk_listener at all.

Comment: I don't think that is actually necessary. I have updated the example in the question to one that does that.

Comment: Well, in Your updated code, button is updated outside main tk thread. This may work if You run it (for a time), but Your approach is not Thread safe. There might be situation when both, main tk thread and reader thread wants to update Your button at the same time and crashing Your application unexpectedly. That's why I was using tk_listener.after() to call thread safe callback to tk.

Comment: So you mean that if the button was to update after clicking it, the text on it could change due to the serial handling while that is still in progress?

Comment: For example, yes. In general, it is a good practice, to just give a callback if You are using two threads and let main tk thread do the work. Think of it as a signal to main Thread. Tk itself will take care of all the complex tasks safely within it's own Thread after receiving that signal. Also, You don't want to do the anything else in Your data_received method, which should only consume messages from serial port and notify Your tk app.

Comment: That seems like a good idea. I have updated the example once again to reflect that, now using the `app` window itself.

Comment: Nevermind, it actually doesn't interrupt whatever the `app` is doing. If a function like updating the text of a button is still being executed, the thread of the reader will not call its function, until it is finished.

Comment: Ok, so if my code is working as You want, please consider my answer as a solution for Your request with bounty. Thanks!