# Multiple serial connections in separate dedicated threads with Tkinter using serial ReaderThread

Tags: python, multithreading, class, tkinter, pyserial

I want to create and maintain multiple non-blocking serial connections with some peripherals over UART. Truthfully, this is an expansion of this [question about tkinter and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70625801/threading-reading-a-serial-port-in-python-with-a-gui)

Domarm suggests the following as a solution to the original question of creating a new thread to handle receiving serial data without blocking the main script. (In the code below I left out the Raw data reader class for simplicity here).

```
import tkinter as tk

from serial import Serial
from serial.threaded import ReaderThread, Protocol, LineReader

class SerialReaderProtocolLine(LineReader):
    tk_listener = None
    TERMINATOR = b'\n\r'

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        """Called when reader thread is started"""
        if self.tk_listener is None:
            raise Exception("tk_listener must be set before connecting to the socket!")
        super().connection_made(transport)
        print("Connected, ready to receive data...")

    def handle_line(self, line):
        """New line waiting to be processed"""
        # Execute our callback in tk
        self.tk_listener.after(0, self.tk_listener.on_data, line)

class MainFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self)
        self.listbox.pack()
        self.pack()

    def on_data(self, data):
        print("Called from tk Thread:", data)
        self.listbox.insert(tk.END, data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = tk.Tk()

    main_frame = MainFrame()
    # Set listener to our reader
    SerialReaderProtocolLine.tk_listener = main_frame
    # Initiate serial port
    serial_port = Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0")
    # Initiate ReaderThread
    reader = ReaderThread(serial_port, SerialReaderProtocolLine)
    # Start reader
    reader.start()

    app.mainloop()
```

This solution works well for a single connection, but what if I want to expand this so I can manage multiple connections at once?

Since this code structure is using the SerialReaderProtocolLine class variable tk_listener, I am unsure of how to go about making this modular so that I can create multiple ReaderThreads with each their own listeners.

Here is an example of me trying to move the class variable tk_listener into a constructor to allow for the creation of a new instance of SerialReaderProtocolLine, which I then try to pass into a new ReaderThread. From that, I get a type error, "TypeError: 'SerialReaderProtocolLine' object is not callable". This error is thrown when I try to pass an instance of SerialReaderProtocolLine to ReaderThread.

```
import tkinter as tk

from serial import Serial
from serial.threaded import ReaderThread, LineReader


class SerialReaderProtocolLine(LineReader):

    def __init__(self, listener, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.tk_listener = listener
        self.TERMINATOR = b'\n\r'

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        """Called when reader thread is started"""
        if self.tk_listener is None:
            raise Exception("tk_listener must be set before connecting to the socket!")
        super().connection_made(transport)
        print("Connected, ready to receive data...")

    def handle_line(self, line):
        """New line waiting to be processed"""
        # Execute our callback in tk
        self.tk_listener.after(0, self.tk_listener.on_data, line)

class MainFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self)
        self.listbox.pack()
        self.pack()

    def on_data(self, data):
        print("Called from tk Thread:", data)
        self.listbox.insert(tk.END, data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = tk.Tk()

    main_frame1 = MainFrame()
    main_frame2 = MainFrame()

    # Set listener to our reader
    reader_listener1 = SerialReaderProtocolLine(main_frame1)
    reader_listener2 = SerialReaderProtocolLine(main_frame2)
    # Initiate serial port
    serial_port1 = Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0")
    serial_port2 = Serial("/dev/ttyUSB1")
    # Initiate ReaderThread
    reader1 = ReaderThread(serial_port1, reader_listener1)
    reader2 = ReaderThread(serial_port2, reader_listener2)
    # Start reader
    reader1.start()
    reader2.start()

    app.mainloop()
```

So because it looks like ReaderThread is trying to create a new instance of SerialProtocolLine, I now try a different approach where I pass the SerialProtocolLine class twice to two different ReaderThread constructors. I reassign the tk_listener class variable inbetween ReaderThread instantiation calls...and this bluescreens my computer upon the first receipt of data!

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = tk.Tk()

    main_frame0 = MainFrame()
    main_frame1 = MainFrame()

    # Set listener to our reader
    SerialReaderProtocolLine.tk_listener = main_frame0
    serial_port0 = Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0")
    reader0 = ReaderThread(serial_port0, SerialReaderProtocolLine)

    # Initiate serial port
    SerialReaderProtocolLine.tk_listener = main_frame1
    serial_port1 = Serial("/dev/ttyUSB1")
    reader1 = ReaderThread(serial_port1, SerialReaderProtocolLine)

    # Start reader
    reader0.start()
    reader1.start()

    app.mainloop()
```

Any suggestions on how to go about making this modular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the instance of `MainFrame` to `SerialReaderProtocolLine` class and use `functools.partial` to pass this extra argument in `ReaderThread(...)`.

Below is the updated code (*note that my platform is Windows, so the com ports used are "COM1" and "COM3", change them to the com ports in your platform*):

```py
from functools import partial
import tkinter as tk
from serial import Serial
from serial.threaded import ReaderThread, LineReader

class SerialReaderProtocolLine(LineReader):
    def __init__(self, tk_listener):
        super().__init__()
        self.tk_listener = tk_listener

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        super().connection_made(transport)
        self.handle_line(f"Connected {self.tk_listener}, ready to receive data ...")

    def handle_line(self, line):
        self.tk_listener.after(1, self.tk_listener.on_data, line)

class MainFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self, width=60)
        self.listbox.pack()
        #self.pack()  # it is not recommended to pack itself, let the parent do it

    def on_data(self, data):
        print("Called from tk Thread:", data)
        self.listbox.insert(tk.END, data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = tk.Tk()

    main_frame1 = MainFrame(app, name="listener1")
    main_frame2 = MainFrame(app, name="listener2")

    main_frame1.pack(side="left")
    main_frame2.pack(side="left")

    serial_port1 = Serial("COM1") # change to your required port name
    serial_port2 = Serial("COM3") # change to your required port name

    reader1 = ReaderThread(serial_port1, partial(SerialReaderProtocolLine, main_frame1))
    reader2 = ReaderThread(serial_port2, partial(SerialReaderProtocolLine, main_frame2))

    reader1.start()
    reader2.start()

    app.mainloop()
```

The result:

[image]